# maven dependency management mechanism, the priority about dependency management which using import scope

Tags: java, maven

There are two examples.

---

example 1.

pom of project A is a simple pom:

```
 <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>kafka-demo</name>
```

pom of project B:

```
    <parent>
    <artifactId>kafka-demo</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>child-one</artifactId>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In this example, spring-boot version of project B is 2.0.3.RELEASE.

example 2.

pom of project A.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>org.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>kafka-demo</name>
```

pom of project B is the same as the previous example.

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>kafka-demo</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>child-one</artifactId>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In the example two, spring-boot version of project B is 2.3.1.RELEASE.

---

My question is in example 2, why the version of spring-boot is 2.3.1, rather than 2.0.3.

> This scope is only supported on a dependency of type pom in the  section. It indicates the dependency to be replaced with the effective list of dependencies in the specified POM's  section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, dependencyManagement that is *directly* declared in the POM is always stronger than `import`ed dependencyManagement.

It is wrong to assume that an `import` is the same as declaring the list from the BOM at the same place.

So in your second example, one of the BOMs is used as parent, so it is directly used in the resulting effective POM, while the other is an `import`, which is less strong.

Comment: "dependencyManagement that is directly declared in the POM is always stronger than imported dependencyManagement"

This seems not entirely correct to me, in my test, the **first place will win** if they are all placed in the same pom.xml.

Comment: @JasonMing Your comment save my life. I used to think that the latter imported ones takes precedence and tried for hours.